# Android Chrome Web Ble Api Start Notification Error

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm developing a pwa application which connects a bluetooth device and reads some data. But I need to get real time notifications from device.I'm trying to test samples on the internet but none of them working for me.

Android Version : 8.1.0

By the way , I'm testing these functions with ngrok and http-server for https.

```js
function onButtonClick() {
  log('Requesting Bluetooth Device...');
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(
    {filters: [{services: ['battery_service']}]})
  .then(device => {
    log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(server => {
    log('Getting Battery Service...');
    return server.getPrimaryService('battery_service');
  })
  .then(service => {
    log('Getting Battery Level Characteristic...');
    return service.getCharacteristic('battery_level');
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    log('Reading Battery Level...');
    return characteristic.readValue();
  })
  .then(value => {
    let batteryLevel = value.getUint8(0);
    log('> Battery Level is ' + batteryLevel + '%');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    log('Argh! ' + error);
  });
}
```

Test - 2

- Phone successfully connects the device but after notification start, nothing happens

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<button id="startBtn">start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">stop</button>
<script>
    function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) {/* do nothing */
        }
    }
    document
        .getElementById("myBtn")
        .addEventListener('pointerup', function (event) {
            onStartButtonClick()
        })

    var myCharacteristic;

    function onStartButtonClick() {

        console.log('Requesting Bluetooth Device...');
        navigator
            .bluetooth
            .requestDevice({
                filters: [
                    {
                        name: "MLCEP"
                    }
                ],
                optionalServices: [
                    parseInt("0x1928"),
                    parseInt("0x4BE9"),
                    parseInt("0x1801"),
                    parseInt("0x65C2"),
                    parseInt("0xEA5D"),
                    parseInt("0x180A"),
                    parseInt("0xC678"),
                    parseInt("0x1800"),
                    parseInt("0xE6D3")
                ]
            })
            .then(device => {
                console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
                return device
                    .gatt
                    .connect();
            })
            .then(server => {
                console.log('Getting Service...');
                return server.getPrimaryService(parseInt('0xC678'));
            })
            .then(service => {
                console.log('Getting Characteristic...');
                return service.getCharacteristic(parseInt('0x0480'));
            })
            .then(characteristic => {
                myCharacteristic = characteristic;
                return myCharacteristic
                    .startNotifications()
                    .then(_ => {
                        console.log('> Notifications started');
                        myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', handleNotifications);
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Argh! ' + error);
            });
    }

    document
        .getElementById("startBtn")
        .addEventListener('pointerup', function (event) {
            myCharacteristic
                .startNotifications()
                .then(_ => {
                    console.log('> Notifications started');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Argh! ' + error);
                });

        })

    document
        .getElementById("stopBtn")
        .addEventListener('pointerup', function (event) {

            myCharacteristic
                .stopNotifications()
                .then(_ => {
                    console.log('> Notifications stop');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Argh! ' + error);
                });

        })

    function handleNotifications(event) {
        let value = event.target.value;
        let a = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < value.byteLength; i++) {
            a.push('0x' + ('00' + value.getUint8(i).toString(16)).slice(-2));
        }
        console.log('> ' + a.join(' '));
        document
            .getElementById("content")
            .innerHTML += a.join(' ') + "<br>"
    }
</script>

<h1>New version 3</h1>
<div id="content"></div>
```

## Remote Debug Console Logs ( Phone ) -> Nothing Happens.

```
test2.html:25 Requesting Bluetooth Device...
test2.html:47 Connecting to GATT Server...
test2.html:53 Getting Service...
test2.html:57 Getting Characteristic...
test2.html:65 > Notifications started
```

# Debug MacOS ( Laptop ) -> This Works Perfectly

```
test2.html:25 Requesting Bluetooth Device...
test2.html:47 Connecting to GATT Server...
test2.html:53 Getting Service...
test2.html:57 Getting Characteristic...
test2.html:65 > Notifications started
test2.html:112 > 0xe5 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe2 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe7 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe4 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe1 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe6 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe3 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe0 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe5 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe2 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe7 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe4 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe1 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:112 > 0xe6 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x88 0xcb 0x1a 0x02 0xec 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
test2.html:95 > Notifications stop
```

Comment: Does the battery service example behave the same as your second test?

Comment: As a note, service IDs are UUIDs, not integers, so using parseInt() isn't necessary. You should pass the value as a string, such as 'C678' for a "short form" UUID or '0000C678-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB' in long form. Note that assigning your own 16-bit service UUIDs is not spec-compliant as all 16-bit UUIDs are reserved for standardized services: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery/

Comment: @ReillyGrant Battery level example works perfectly. Only start notification has problems. But I came up with a new status. I can get notifications when the data size is 1 byte but if data size is larger than 20 bytes I cannot receive those

Comment: @MehmetaliSaraç You may want to share logs to help us debug this issue. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs